# Downloaded Image not complete but the image still shows cut using Android?

Tags: android, android-image

I have an Android application that downloads some images, using normally. Most of the times, when an error occurs (network, disk space, ...etc) an exception is thrown, an I just know and delete the downloaded file in `catch` block.

However, sometimes, the download is not complete and the image is shown but cut off. (i.e. half of image is visible and the left part is shown white)

Any suggestions on how to detect this error so that I delete the file and request the user to download it again?

Here is code:

```
private static int downloadFile(byte[] buffer, String fromUrl, File saveTo) {
    URL url;
    boolean conn = true;
    try {
        url = new URL(fromUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("connection", "close");
        connection.connect();
        // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
        // instead of the file
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            return DOWNLOAD_SERVER_INVALID_RESPONSE;
        //int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
        // download the file
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        conn = false;
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(saveTo);
        int count;
        //long total = 0;
        while ((count = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, count);
            //total += count;
        }
        input.close();
        output.close();
        return DOWNLOAD_OK;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return DOWNLOAD_MALFORMED_URL;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return DOWNLOAD_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return DOWNLOAD_SERVER_INVALID_RESPONSE;
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return DOWNLOAD_SERVER_INVALID_RESPONSE;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return conn ? DOWNLOAD_SERVER_INVALID_RESPONSE : DOWNLOAD_IO_EXCEPTION;
    }
}
```

Comment: any error from logcat ?

Comment: The problem is that this problem occurs randomly at production (rarely). I cannot reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess since the image you explained is a half downloaded image, you could do something like check how much of the image was actually downloaded, and then decide whether to delete or keep based on that. In you code , the line `int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();` will help you do this. Just check if *fileLength* and the downloaded image file length is equal or near to be equal. If it is, then it has been downloaded successfully. I'm guessing, just guessing, that the code would be something like this:

```
int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
if (fileLength != -1) {
    if (fileLength == file.length()) {
        System.out.println("file is complete");
    } else {
        System.out.println("file is incomplete");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("unknown if file is complete");
}
```

Tweak it a little and you should probably get what you want.

**OR**

As greenapps pointed out, you could also use this approach:

1. Assign an int variable `int totalcount = 0;`
2. Increment that in a loop with `totalcount += count;`
3. After the loop is complete, compare *totalcount* with *fileLength*

Comment: You first should introduce an int variable `int totalcount = 0;` And increment that in the loop with `totalcount += count;` Then after the loop compare totalcount with ContentLength.

Comment: @greenapps Isn't that the same as using the length() function?

Comment: yes I get that, but the final result would be the same, right? So why go with a counter when you can finish it in one function?

Comment: I would not guarantee that the final result would be te same. Those checks should not be needed to begin with.

Comment: @greenapps Why not guarantee? Can file size be different than content-length? Also, can the same file size differ per device?

Comment: If you want to guarantee this then please do. I dont.